# android youtube player get current frame

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to know if there is a way to get current frame as a bitmap from an integrated yoube player from a youtubePlayerFragment.

I didn't find such method, and I already tried to extract a bimap from fragment's view but the bitmap doesn't contains the drawing elements from the video I only have buttons and progress bar. Any one knows how to get it?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the reference found in [Package Summary for Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary) and it seems this feature is not yet supported.

Also, I found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/AFFe2YVHLOc) that this kind of action may be violating Youtube's terms.